# yii migrate/create Error: Unknown option --fields

Tags: yii2, migration

I am trying to migrate create table fields using

```
yii migrate/create create_post_table --fields="title:string,body:text"
```

but throws

```
Error: Unknown option --fields
```

what should I do? please help.

Comment: What is the Yii 2 version you are using?

Comment: Thanks for yor reply @Bizley.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

`fields` option is available from Yii 2.0.7. Update your Yii 2 framework.